# C++ shared_ptr and direct buffer enqueueing. How?

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-ptr

I need to make small code refactoring i queueing/dequeueing operation in multi-thread application. Current implementation is:

- enqueueing function is called with argument:

  ```
  enqueue(obj_ptr item)
  ```

  where *obj_ptr* is pointer to class *obj* created using **shared_ptr**. Then, given items (type obj_ptr) are enqueued in std list

  ```
  list<obj_ptr>
  ```

  and simply dequeued using front() and pop_front() and sent further. Everything works fine in this implementation.
- What i want to do is:

  Enqueue this items in special list using its API:

  ```
  a_enqueue(void *buffer)
  ```

  So I need the direct address to buffer.

I was thinking about use:

```
    item->get()
```

which returns type *obj* but then I could only dequeue *obj*, not *obj_ptr* which is expected to next operations after dequeueing (+ I would loose information about class references and it will destroy multi-thread app)

I was thinking about provide to list pointer to *obj_ref item*:

```
    a_enqueue(&item)
```

But *item* is created in some function long time ago and put as argument many times (not as pointer) and it is not possible to find direct address to it.

The best way for me is to enqueue buffer *obj* (item->get()), then dequeue and find somehow the same reference *obj_ptr item* I used in get(). Is it possible? Any other ideas?

Thanks.

Edit: Dequeue call is:

```
 a_dequeue(void **buffer)
```

Comment: Why do you want to enqueue a raw pointer?

Comment: It's about queue's API

Answer (score 0):

What does the API dequeue look like?

Usually if you're enqueueing `void *`, you're also defining a handler function so you can do something like this...

```
void enqueue_ptr (obj_ptr enqueue_me)
{
  // Making a copy on the heap increments the ptr count
  obj_ptr * heap_ptr = new obj_ptr(enqueue_me);
  a_enqueue (heap_ptr);
}


obj_ptr dequeue_ptr (void)
{
  // You might need casting to change void * to obj_ptr *
  obj_ptr * heap_ptr;
  a_dequeue (&heap_ptr);

  // Sticking the copy in an auto_ptr decrements the ptr count when we leave scope.
  std::auto_ptr<obj_ptr> obj_pptr(heap_ptr);
  return *obj_pptr;
}
```

Basically, you treat the obj_ptr the same as you would any other object being passed around as a void *.

Comment: a_enqueue(void *), a_dequeue(void*) only. You said that I can treat the obj_ptr same as other objects? Is there solution like a_enqueue(cast<void*> item)  where item is of type obj_ptr = shared_ptr<obj> ?

Comment: Please add the header declaration of a_dequeue to the question.